# Gedit: how to disable auto-completion in search/replace window

Tags: gedit, auto-completion

I am using Gedit 3.28.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 64bit as my favourite script editor.

Gedit not only stores some of my newest search/replace strings so that I can select them from the drop-down list in the search/replace window. It also auto-completes the strings when I enter them in the "search" or the "replace" field, and needless to say that the auto-completed strings are almost always useless.

This is extremely annoying, and it's an unnecessary source for errors.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to turn auto-complete off, neither in the GUI options, nor in the help file.

Comment: I fear the situation has not changed since 2008: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2008-July/msg00023.html